# Why is this Math.random() statement set out in this format?

Tags: java, random

I'm  complete beginner to Java so I am sorry for what is probably a very stupid question. This is a programme for guessing two random numbers. Why is the Math.random followed by "* (MAX + 1 - MIN))) + MIN;". Also how does the Math.random know to generate a number between 1 and 3 and not anything higher?

```
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  final int MIN = 1, MAX = 3;
  int firstAnswer = ((int)(Math.random() * (MAX + 1 - MIN))) + MIN;
  int secondAnswer = ((int)(Math.random() * (MAX + 1 - MIN))) + MIN;
  int firstGuess, secondGuess;
```

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: If any of the answers here helps, you may want to accept their solution. Unless your problem is still unresolved, then you may leave a comment.

Answer (score 4):

`Math.random()` generates a `double` in range [0, 1). If you multiply it by (3+1-1), and cast it to int, you get a number in range [0, 3). Since the number is now an `int`, it means that it's in range [0, 2]. If you sum it with 1, you get an integer in range [1, 3], that is either 1, 2 or 3.

Answer (score 2):

`Math.random()` generates a `double` number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive).

The multiplication by `(MAX + 1 - MIN)`, casting to `int` and addition of `MIN` transform the generated `double` to an `int` value between `1` and `3`.